# Multiple counters in a single for loop : Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Is it possible in Python to run multiple counters in a single for loop as in C/C++?

I would want something like -- `for i,j in x,range(0,len(x)):` I know Python interprets this differently and why, but how would I run two loop counters concurrently in a single for loop?

Comment: Aside (since you probably don't want to use it in this case): `range(0, len(x)) == range(len(x))`

Answer (score 36):

You want `zip` in general, which combines two iterators, as @S.Mark says. But in this case `enumerate` does exactly what you need, which means you don't have to use `range` directly:

```
for j, i in enumerate(x):
```

Note that this gives the index of `x` first, so I've reversed `j, i`.

Answer (score 24):

You might want to use [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for i,j in zip(x,range(0,len(x))):
```

Example,

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> print zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> for a,b in zipped:
...     print a,b
...
1 4
2 5
3 6
>>>
```

**Note**: The correct answer for this question is `enumerate` as other mentioned, zip is general option to have multiple items in a single loop

Comment: `zip` is good, but in this particular case, `enumerate` is the usual way of doing what the original poster wants.

Answer (score 6):

```
for i,j in enumerate(x)
```